# Meaning of "do the bill"

Tags: meaning

In one episode of the Friends series, joey and chandler are talking about their electric bill Here's the script:

> Joey: This is how much we pay for electric?!!!
>
> Chandler: Uh, yeah.(Joey runs over and shuts off the lights.)
>
> Chandler: So, **we’ll do the rest of the bills later then?**

I don't get this part exactly: **"we’ll do the rest of the bills later then?"**

Comment: What exactly don't you get?  Do is a verb that can be used very generally, for whatever they were doing - examining the bills/looking at the bills to check what they have to pay.

Comment: Acutally when he says this : all laugh, if this means to check or pay for the bill, there is no need to laugh, maybe he means in the dark you cannot check the bills?

Comment: Yes, that is why the audience is laughing. You can't read the bills in the dark. It's just a joke.

Comment: Yeah, it's partly funny because you can't read bills in the dark, but also maybe partly funny because Joey thinks turning off the lights will mean they don't use any electricity. In fact the fridge etc is still using electricity - ha ha Joey is stupid. And other bills like rent can't be avoided so easily, so Chandler could be saying "You think you can stop using electricity, but it'll be harder to avoid other bills".

Comment: do the bills = "look at and pay the bill" (with a check for example) or decide who owes what amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first dictionary definition of the verb *to do* is:

> perform (an action, the precise nature of which is often unspecified).

It is a very general purpose verb to carry out almost any other action - actions which themselves may be verbs.

Whatever Joey and Chandler were 'doing' with the bills had already been established - my guess is they had agreed to look through all their bills one by one. So, having established the task and begun to *do* it, they could break off and say "*we'll do the rest of the bills later*", meaning they will continue the task later, with the remaining bills.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly “do the bill”, it's “*…**do** **the rest of** the bills later*”.

Opening envelopes, looking at the cost and (in those days) choosing when to pay bills are all tasks which, if you are short of money, are also unpleasant. Joey is already frightened by this electricity bill, the thought of handing other utility bills is, in a word, scary.

Moreover, in English we often use the verb *do* for household jobs;
e.g. ***do*** *the washing, the shopping, the cleaning, the cooking* etc.